# How to change host machine time for Kubernetes cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, kubernetes, azure-aks

How do I change system time (not timezone) for all containers deployed on Azure Kubernetes cluster?

Can this be changed from inside container / pods? I guess it should be changeable from host machine. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

Time comes from the underlying kernel and that is not something that you will be able to adjust from code that runs in a pod.

Even if you could, I suspect it would cause a whole heap of trouble; the pod time and api-server time would be inconsistent and that won't end well!

Comment: I agree. Don't do this. All kinds of systems, like TLS for example, depend on system times being in agreement or at least close enough. But if you really wanted to maybe you could run your own (wrong) NTP server and sync to that.